# Matlab to Opencv Code

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, image-processing

```
I = imread('C:\\Users\\20055316\\Desktop\\blurMetric\\Illumination_Changes\\z_0001.bmp');
I = double(I);
[y, x] = size(I);

Hv = [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]/9;
Hh = Hv';

B_Ver = imfilter(I,Hv);%blur the input image in vertical direction
B_Hor = imfilter(I,Hh);%blur the input image in horizontal direction
```

I need to convert the above Matlab code to OpenCV,
i tried using Filter2D but did not get the desired result.
The openCV code is as shown below

```
Mat oMatTempImage = imread("C:\\Users\\20055316\\Desktop\\blurMetric\\Illumination_Changes\\z_0001.bmp");
    cvtColor(oMatTempImage, oMatTempImage, CV_BGR2RGB);
    oMatTempImage.convertTo(oMatTempImage, CV_32FC3);
Mat oMatVerticalKernel = Mat(1, 9, CV_32FC1);
    for (int nColItr = 0; nColItr < 9; nColItr++)
    {
        oMatVerticalKernel.at<float>(0, nColItr) = 1.0f / 9.0f;
    }
    Mat oMatHorizontalKernel;
    transpose(oMatVerticalKernel, oMatHorizontalKernel);
Mat oMatVeriticalBlurr;
    filter2D(oMatTempImage, oMatVeriticalBlurr, -1, oMatVerticalKernel);
Mat oMatHorizontalBlurr;
    filter2D(oMatTempImage, oMatHorizontalBlurr, -1, oMatHorizontalKernel);
```

i am not getting similar results, Kindly help me out please.

EDIT :
Thank you guys for your responses,
i got to know what was the issue.
Matlab internally does zero padding when imfilter() function is called, where as opencv doesn't do it. I had to zero pad  before applying the filter and remove the zero padded pixels later. This solved the problem.

Comment: What's the result? I'm assuming you know what you're doing with the conversions at the beginning

Comment: @MarcoA.yes i m trying to convert the image from uchar to floating point type, all i want to know, is filter2D the right approach to convert Matlab imfilter to opencv, if No, how do i proceed ?

Comment: @Barry yes, these are equivalent (although there are easier ways of writing your OpenCV code). Please post the images which show dissimilar results.

Comment: One obvious difference is that your matlab code operates on doubles, and your openCV code operates on singles (floats). How specifically are the results different?

Comment: Have you tried [`sepfilter2D`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#sepfilter2d)?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you could use the Blur or GaussianBlur functions. Some examples here: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/gausian_median_blur_bilateral_filter/gausian_median_blur_bilateral_filter.html